# Why ajax method calls error function?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have jquery script, which sends ajax request to servlet. It works, it posts text data to servlet *correctly*, but then it calls error function, instead of success function(I checked, servlet send back to ajax *not null* string).

Why ajax method calls error function?

Here's code of script

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login-button").click(function () {
            var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
            var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8181/library/login",
                data: {login: userLogin, password: userPassword},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "1") {
                        document.location.href = "http://localhost:8181/library/workshop.html";
                    }
                    if (data == "2") {
                        document.location.href = "http://localhost:8181/library/library.html";
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error report\n" + "jqXHR = " + jqXHR + "\n" + "textStatus = " + textStatus + "\n" +
                            "errorThrown =  " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Here's code of servlet

```
    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    SocketConnection.output.println("log_in " + login + " " + password);
    out.print(SocketConnection.input.readLine());
    out.close();
        }

    }
```

The textStatus value is `error`, the errorThrown value is void, in the error report.

Comment: `SocketConnection.output` stores inner logic of connection with application, which connects to database.

Comment: Are you sure the datatype (text) is correct  -- "text": A plain text string. It will help to prove that what comes from the server is actually a string

Comment: `SocketConnection.input.readLine()` returns `string`, and as datatype in `ajax` i can choose from `xml`, `json`, `script`, or `html` and `text`. I think, that `java` `String` according to `text`, or it is not correct?

Comment: not sure how HttpServletRequest work -- try ---  cosole.log(data) --- in the success function and post the result in the Q. use devtools on the browser to access the console

Comment: But this is problem, it somehow never reaches success function. Even it sends data correctly.

Comment: i see, then the error is in the java code. try --  System.out.println(out)  to see what it says

Comment: System.out.println(SocketConnection.input.readLine()) has value "1", and  System.out.println(out) has value "org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter@1350d0e3"

Answer (score 0):

if it is returning status 200
your function contains the following setting

```
dataType: "text",
```

it might be not sending the text. just try to remove this setting and I hope it will work fine